Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature key was not found"
I am new to asp.net identity and jwt token authentification and having trouble authorizing API endpoints, or more exactly making calls to enpoints that require authorization. I created an Asp.net Core API with a custom database to which i added Identity on the user table. Everything worked fine untill i added the JWT Authentication. Then all the enpoints that require authorization fail : 401 UNAUTHORIZED Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature key was not found".
This is what i have in Program.Cs :
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        var configuration = builder.Configuration;
        builder.Logging.AddConsole();

        var host = builder.Configuration["DBHOST"];
        var port = builder.Configuration["DBPORT"];
        var user = builder.Configuration["DBUSER"];
        var password = builder.Configuration["DBPASSWORD"];
        var database = builder.Configuration["DBNAME"];

        builder.Services.AddCors(policy =>
        {
            policy.AddPolicy("CorsAllAccessPolicy", opt =>
            opt.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
        });

        var connectionString = $"Server={host},{port};Database={database};User Id={user};Password={password};TrustServerCertificate=True;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=False;";

        //var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<GrdbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        ConfigureAutoMapper(builder.Services);

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbService, DbService>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(x => new BlobServiceClient("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://storage:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://storage:10001/devstoreaccount1;"));

        builder.Services.AddIdentity<GrdbUser, IdentityRole<int>>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GrdbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = configuration["JWT:VAlidAudience"],
                ValidIssuer = configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:SecretKey"]))
            };
        });


        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        //builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "GRDB Database", Version = "v1" });

            // Define JWT bearer token authentication
            var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = "bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT"
            };
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", securityScheme);

            // Make sure Swagger UI requires a Bearer token
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            }
        },
        Array.Empty<string>()
    }
});
        });


        var app = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<GrdbContext>();
            InitializeDatabase(dbContext);
        }

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        //if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        //{
        //    app.UseSwagger();
        //    app.UseSwaggerUI();
        //}
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
        app.UseCors("CorsAllAccessPolicy");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }


    static void ConfigureAutoMapper(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<BookAuthor, AuthorDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<BookAuthor, AuthorCreateDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<BookGenre, GenreDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<BookGenre, GenreCreateDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<BookAuthorConnection, AuthorDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<BookGenreConnection, GenreDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<BookReview, BookReviewDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<BookReview, BookReviewCreateDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<BookReview, BookReviewUpdateDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<GrdbUser, GrdbUserDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<GrdbUser, GrdbUserCreateDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<GrdbUser, GrdbUserUpdateDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookCreateDTO>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookUpdateDTO>().ReverseMap();
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
    }

    public static void InitializeDatabase(GrdbContext dbContext)
    {
        // Apply any pending migrations
        dbContext.Database.Migrate();

        // Add your custom initialization logic here
        // For example, you can seed initial data or create additional tables

        // Save the changes to the database
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

And this is what i have in appSettings :
"JWT": {
  "SecretKey": "secretpa$$word",
  "ValidIssuer": "grdb.adminui.server",
  "ValidAudience": "grdb.clients",
  "ExpirationInMinutes": 1440
}

Then i created an AuthenticationController that looks like this :
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   [ApiController]
   public class AuthenticateController : ControllerBase
   {
       private readonly UserManager<GrdbUser> _userManager;
       private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> _roleManager;
       private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;


       public AuthenticateController(
           UserManager<GrdbUser> userManager,
           RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> roleManager,
           IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           _userManager = userManager;
           _roleManager = roleManager;
           _configuration = configuration;

       }

       [HttpPost]
       [Route("login")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
       {
           var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
           if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
           {
               var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

               var authClaims = new List<Claim>
               {
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                   new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
               };

               foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
               {
                   authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
               }

               if (authClaims.Count > 0)
               {
                   var token = GetToken(authClaims);

                   return Ok(new AuthenticationResult
                   {
                       Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                       Expiration = token.ValidTo,
                       User = new LoggedUser
                       {
                           Id = user.Id,
                           Username = user.UserName,
                           Email = user.Email,
                           Roles = (List<string>)userRoles
                       }
                   });
               }
           }
           return Unauthorized();
       }

       [HttpPost]
       [Route("register")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
       {
           var userExists = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
           if (userExists != null)
               return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User already exists!" });

           GrdbUser user = new()
           {
               Email = model.Email,
               SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
               UserName = model.Username,
           };
           var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
           if (!result.Succeeded)
               return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User creation failed! Please check user details and try again." });

           return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "User created successfully!" });
       }


       //[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
       [HttpPost]
       [Route("register-admin")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAdmin([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
       {
           var userExists = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
           if (userExists != null)
               return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User already exists!" });

           GrdbUser user = new()
           {
               Email = model.Email,
               SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
               UserName = model.Username
           };
           var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
           if (!result.Succeeded)
               return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User creation failed! Please check user details and try again." });

           if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))
               await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>(UserRoles.Admin));
           if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.User))
               await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>(UserRoles.User));

           if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))
           {
               await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Admin);
           }
           if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))
           {
               await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.User);
           }
           return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "User created successfully!" });
       }

       private JwtSecurityToken GetToken(List<Claim> authClaims)
       {
           var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:SecretKey"]));
           var algorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256;
           if (key.KeySize < 256)
           {
               // Generate a new key with the required size (128 bits)
               var newKey = new byte[256 / 8];
               new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(newKey);
               key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(newKey);
           }

           var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, algorithm);
           var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
               issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
               audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
               claims: authClaims,
               expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
               signingCredentials: creds);

           return token;

       }

Then i swagger i can create an user and then upon login i get this :
swagger login
Then i use the token to Authorize Swagger and get authorized,but when i am trying to use a Post endpoint that need authorization i get this :
swagger_post
I have also tried to login and make HTTP requests (with headers) from a React app and from a Blazor app. The login works but the requests provide the same error.
Maybe usefull information : both the API and the SQL server run inside a multi project docker container using docker compose. I use for the registered users the tables that Asp.net Core Identity created.
Can someone please help me figure out what am i doing wrong! Thank you in advance!
Project Package :
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>..\..</DockerfileContext>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
    <UserSecretsId>8c5328fc-9e82-4bef-a6d7-86ddb66d3549</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.19.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azurite" Version="2.6.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="7.0.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="7.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.18">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.18">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.7.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\GRDB.AdminUI.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\GRDB.AdminUI.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>


tried different ways to setup jwt authentication and different ways to generate tokens, but failed

What's your project packages like?

Updated with project packages

You have "  "ValidAudience":" in your appsetings, but you have   ValidAudience = configuration["JWT:VAlidAudience"],  in your program.cs. Try to keep the same.

unfortunatelly, that did not fix the problem. Still 401 unauthorized when making http requests

Have a try like:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78259585/unable-to-validate-jwt-token-net-core-6/78259690#78259690 ?

Thank you, @QingGuo ! Your post instruction led me to detect that the SecretKey was to short and that was causing the problems.
